# Communication between class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I can call a class from another class but not vice versa.

From `class A` (see below), I can call `Method_B` located in `class B` but from `class B`, I am not able to call `Method_A1` or `Method_A2` located in `class A`.

I got the following error:

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

test_1.py:

```
from test_2 import *

class A():

    def __init__(self):

        self.key = 1
        self.call_Method_B = B().Method_B(self.key)

    def Method_A1(self):
        print("Method_A1: ok")

    def Method_A2(self):
        print("Method_A2: ok")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_A = A()
```

test_2.py:

```
class B():

    def Method_B(self,key):
        self.key = key

        if self.key ==1:
            self.call_Method_A1 = A().Method_A1()
        else:
            self.call_Method_A2 = A().Method_A2()
```

Comment: If at all possible, this arrangement would be better to avoid than to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate between scripts you need to import test_1 as a module:

```
from test_1 import *
```

and change the way you call `A` to like this:

```
if self.key ==1:
    self.call_Method_A1 = A.Method_A1(self)
else:
    self.call_Method_A2 = A.Method_A2(self)
```

Comment: With the following edit to your answer it's work fine: `self.call_Method_A1 = A.Method_A1(self)`

Comment: @H. Dave Ah yeah, sorry didn't read test_1 carefully enough.  That is required because Method_A1 and Method_A2 require one positional value.  Which is self because they are inherited from the class in test_1.py

Answer (score 1):

You have a loop in your imports.  Try adding an import like this:

```
class B():

    def Method_B(self,key):
        from test_1 import A
        ....
```

This will then only import `A` from test_1 after it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass class `A` as an argument when calling `Method_B`

test_1.py:

```
from test_2 import *

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = 1
        self.call_Method_B = B().Method_B(self.key, A)

    ...
```

test_2.py:

```
class B():

    def Method_B(self, key, A):
        ...
```

A more conventional way of showing this would be:

```
# test_1.py

from test_2 import B

class A():

    def __init__(self):
        self.key = 1
        self.b = B(self)
        self.b.method_b(self.key)

    @staticmethod
    def method_a1():
        print("Method_A1: ok")

    @staticmethod
    def method_a2():
        print("Method_A2: ok")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_a = A()



# test_2.py

class B():

    def __init__(self, instance_of_a):
        self.a = instance_of_a

    def method_b(self, key):
        self.key = key

        if self.key == 1:
            self.a.method_a1()
        else:
            self.a.method_a2()
```